# Image map with overlay not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, imagemap

I am trying to create an interactive map with an overlay using html image maps.
To see it, please visit: http://www.surge.ca/testing/WFA2100/index.html

---

**The explanation:**

When you hover over an `<area>` of the map, it bring up an overlay with links.
To prevent the overlay from closing when you move to it, as you are no longer hovering over the area, I am using a `setTimeout` before it closes the overlay.

---

**The problem:**

It works like I want in every browser but IE.
In IE 7 and 8, when you hover over an overlay that is above another `<area>`, it immediately switches to the overlay of that `<area>`.

At first, I thought it was a z-index issue where the `<area>`'s z-index was above the overlay, but I think my z-index is set up correctly. I am also thinking that it could just be how IE handles image maps?

---

**The code:**

Here is the code that sets up the events.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // binds mouseenter and mouseleave to <area>
    $('area').bind('mouseenter',function(){
        sectionNum = this.hash;
        sectionNum = sectionNum.replace(/#/,'');
        showOverlay(sectionNum);
        clearTimeout(timer);    
    }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
        timerClose();
    });

    $('.map_info').bind('mouseenter', function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
        timerClose();
    });
});

// sets timer before closing to allow cancel
var timer;
function timerClose(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){hideOverlay();},500);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in IE 9, unfortunately I don't have access to the other browsers at the moment.

Comment: While still Microsoft and therefore inherently flawed, IE9 is vastly superior to all previous incarnations of IE. I'm not surprised it works.

Comment: In the end, I did something similar to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024479/is-there-a-way-to-fire-over-events-ignoring-z-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024479/is-there-a-way-to-fire-over-events-ignoring-z-index) where I track the overlay position and mouse position to stop the other `<area>` events from firing. Not ideal, and takes up some more processing as tracking mouse movement is, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE clear the `setTimeout` when hover ends. I didn't ran your code but I had same problem and cpuld fix it by passing the `setTimeout` function as an string.

For example `setTimeout(alert('hi'), 1000)` wasn't working on a function that was running in a hover state but `setTimeout("alert('hi')", 1000)` was working. 
In your code maybe replacing

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){hideOverlay();},500);
```

with

```
timer = setTimeout("function(){hideOverlay();}",500);
```

solve the problem.
It seems IE run code that passed in string in global scope.

Also I can see you have jQuery in your page. There is a jQuery plug-in called [hoverIntent](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) that do hover delay very nice. Maybe plug-in writer wrote more cross-browser code.

Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this didn't fix the problem.