# Triggering events for the DOM elements with lower Z-index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me out , on how to trigger events for DOM elements having lower z-index value .

//HTML code

```
...
<div>
//Hihger Z-index element
<div id="element1" style="position: absolute;Z-index:5; height: 500px; width: 900px;"></div>    

//Lower Z-index element
<div id="element2" style="position: absolute;Z-index:2; height: 500px; width: 900px;"></div>  
</div>
```

//Binding Events

```
$("#element2").on("mouseenter",function() {alert("Problem with lower z-index")});
```

If I set a higher Z-index value for the #element2 the event is triggered.

Comment: add  pointer-events:none to your css code  #element1{ pointer-events:none; }  read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: You cannot. `element1` is positioned over `element2`. So it catches all the events. If `element1` was a child of `element2` it would work since the event bubbles. How would you push a button if there is a glass panel in front of it?

Comment: Please find solution here. Similar answer responded here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024479/is-there-a-way-to-fire-over-events-ignoring-z-index

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add pointer-events:none to your css code #element1{ pointer-events:none; }  read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)   .  check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/s0072fje/)

The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events. When this property is unspecified, the same characteristics of the visiblePainted value apply to SVG content.

```
  <div>
       //Hihger Z-index element
        <div id="element1" style="position: absolute;Z-index:5; height: 500px; width: 900px;pointer-events:none;"></div>    

     //Lower Z-index element
     <div id="element2" style="position: absolute;Z-index:2; height: 500px; width: 900px;"></div>  
 </div>
```